# index a mongo db with javascript

Tags: javascript, mongodb, indexing, mongodb-indexes

I have working script which stores the html forms i have created in mongoDB.  It works awesome.  However, i can't search any of the data i place in mongo, because i don't have an index.

I realize I could create the index from the console, but for my system to work the way we need, I really need the index to be created when the data is stored.  So, i need to place code in the javascript that actually creates the code 9using node.js or directly).

I tried the following javascript (with node.js), but it does not appear to work.

```
app.post('/:db/:collection/formSubmit', function(req, res) {
    var json = form2json.transform(req.rawBody);    
    var db = new mongo.Db(req.params.db, new mongo.Server(config.db.host, config.db.port,mongoOptions ));
        db.open(function(err, db) {
        db.authenticate(config.db.username, config.db.password, function () {
        db.collection(req.params.collection, function(err, collection) {
      collection.insert(Array.isArray(json) ? json[0] : json, function(err, docs) {
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    if(req.is('application/xml')) {
    res.send('<ok>1<ok>')
    } else {
    es.send(json, 201);       
    } 
// my attempt to create an index while posting a form follows
    db.core.ensureIndex( { "document": 1 } )    
        db.close();
        });
    });
  });
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

You need to call [`ensureIndex`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#ensureindex) on the collection:

```
collection.ensureIndex({ "document": 1 }, function (err, indexName) {    
    db.close();
});
```